# AMD Ryzen 7 3750H running below base speed

Tags: cpu, performance, windows-11, clockspeed, underclock

I noticed that my laptop was getting very sloppy when it was not plugged in. So I dug up the metrics and found that my CPU was running at 1.38GHz, which well below it's base speed of 2.30GHz.
And the clock speed is an amazing 3.38GHz when it is plugged in (which is not an issue). I am not sure why it is happening and how can I fix this, Here are screenshots for reference:

CPU speed when laptop is on battery:
[image: Metrics when laptop is running on battery]

CPU speed when laptop is plugged in:
[image: Metrics when laptop is plugged in]

Comment: Have you checked the power profile? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-the-power-mode-for-your-windows-pc-c2aff038-22c9-f46d-5ca0-78696fdf2de8#Category=Windows_11 You should use the High Performance Power Plan. The processor can change its clock speed (when saving the battery power or if there is not much running).

Comment: The solution worked like a charm I was digging complex metrics and deep into the CPU architecture and wondering if the I managed to damage the bios somehow, when the solution was at the most obvious place. Thank you for the help my friend, you are a legend :D

Comment: I love you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of Power Mode settings as I figured out that my laptop somehow switched to powersaver mode from balanced mode. the solution can be found in [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-the-power-mode-for-your-windows-pc-c2aff038-22c9-f46d-5ca0-78696fdf2de8#Category=Windows_11) thanks to [Gantendo](https://superuser.com/users/1482432/gantendo)